# what is$ f^{(n+1)}(x)$ as a function

Tags: functional-analysis, recreational-mathematics

Define $f^{(n+1)}(x)$ in function form.
Is it $f(f^{(n)}(x))$ or is it $f^{(n)}(x)*f(x)$. Or is it something else completey. Thank you so much. I'm actually studying functions and this was something that just poped into my head. So please let me know.

Comment: Most probably the $(n+1)$th *derivative* of $f$ at point $x$.

Comment: If u were to represent it as a function how would u do it???

Comment: What context did you encounter/are you thinking of this in? If you've been using functional iterates then your first form is correct - but it's non-standard to use parenthesis for the exponent there.

Comment: I'm talking in context of iterated function...

Comment: Plz help me out here...

Answer (score 2):

Mathematicians are indeed not all too consistent here.

It is generally agreed that $f^{(n)}$ denotes the $n^{\rm th}$ derivative of $f$. E.g., if $f(x):=e^{\lambda x}$, then $f^{(n)}(x)=\lambda^n \>e^{\lambda x}$ for all  integers $n\geq0$.

With $f^n$, $\>n\in{\mathbb Z}$, it is another matter. While everyone would interpret $\sin^2 x$ as $\bigl(\sin x\bigr)^2$ the term $f^{-1}$, as in $\sin^{-1}x$, can mean the inverse function of $f$, in the example: $\arcsin$, but it could also denote the reciprocal ${1\over f}\,$. In most cases it is clear from the context what is meant. If you want to emphasize the intended meaning you can write $f^{\circ n}$ for the $n^{\rm th}$ iterate of $f$, which is certainly preferable to $f^{(n)}$.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of functional iterates, we generally write
$$f^{n+1}(x)=f^n(f(x))$$
or, equivalently
$$f^{n+1}(x)=f(f^{n}(x))$$
or even
$$f^{a+b}(x)=f^{a}(f^{b}(x)).$$

Typically, parenthesis aren't used in the exponent of functional iterates (though I *have* seen it), because parenthesis are usually used to disambiguate between functional iteration (no parenthesis) and higher derivatives (with parenthesis).

Comment: Thank You so much. It really means a lot 2 me...

Comment: What is the difference between the two as d representation is the same....

Comment: @Swapnil The difference between the equalities I wrote? They are all equivalent ways of expressing the same thing - it doesn't matter if we apply $f$ first $n$ times then one more, or if we apply it once then $n$ more. (The difference between functional iteration and higher derivatives is much more pronounced; they are really two entirely different ideas)

Comment: Let's assume if iterated functions were differentiated... Then can they b written back in iterated form or vice versa??